# Haproxy ssl redirecting

Tags: ssl, redirect, haproxy

I'm not sure if I understand how to haproxy works exactly. I have system which is composed of few servers with communication based on http. I want to use haproxy as load balancer and something like https server at the same time. It should work following: user write address and haproxy decide - if it is http then it redirect it to https, if it https it connect with the system via http. I mean that only client with haproxy should have https connection, but haproxy with system should have http. Here's the image with described architecture:

[image]

I wrote haproxy configuration file and only what I get is redirecting from http to https and show first site - rest is dead, because all communications look like:

> client --(https)--> haproxy --(https)-->system

instead of

> client --(https)--> haproxy --(http)-->system

Is it possible to create it with haproxy?

Below is my haproxy configuration file:

```
global
    pidfile /var/run/haproxy.pid
    log 127.0.0.1 local2 debug
    maxconn 2048
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
    ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
    crt-base /etc/ssl/private

defaults
    mode        http
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    log global
    option      httplog
    option dontlognull
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    option redispatch
    option tcp-smart-accept 
    option tcp-smart-connect
    timeout http-request 10s
    timeout queue 1m
    timeout connect 5s
    timeout client 2m
    timeout server 2m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check 5s
    retries 3
    compression algo gzip
    compression type text/html text/html;charset=utf-8 text/plain text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript application/ecmascript application/rss+xml application/atomsvc+xml application/atom+xml application/atom+xml;type=entry application/atom+xml;type=feed application/cmisquery+xml application/cmisallowableactions+xml application/cmisatom+xml application/cmistree+xml application/cmisacl+xml application/msword application/vnd.ms-excel application/vnd.ms-powerpoint

frontend https-in
    bind *:80
    redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/cert.pem
    capture request header X-Forwarded-For len 64
    capture request header User-agent len 256
    capture request header Cookie len 64
    capture request header Accept-Language len 64
    rspadd Strict-Transport-Security:\ max-age=15768000
    option contstats
    default_backend share-https

backend share-https
    option httpchk GET /share
    balance roundrobin
    cookie JSESSIONID prefix
    server main srv1:9080 cookie main check inter 5000 weight 4
    server secondary srv2:9080 cookie secondary check inter 5000 weight 1
```

Comment: Your config looks right to me. What do you mean by `...and show first site...`? Have you confirmed that the servers in `share-https` are up?

Comment: Yes, servers are up. I mean that I can see only first page (login) which does not use redirecting in system (between differents servers), but when I try log in (what need redirection between services on servers) it fails. I checked it without https in haproxy and it works so I conclude that there is a problem.

Comment: Can you post a curl trace of a login attempt?

Comment: This is full [curl trace](http://txt.do/an1cg). As you can see it is https request. I would like to connect with haproxy via https, but haproxy should connect with service via http.

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. It wasn't haproxy.cfg, but CSRFPolicy on the server side. Working solution is [here](http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/alfresco-tips-and-tricks-13-csrf-filter-error-on-share-login-with-apache-mod_proxy-and-sslengine-on/)

Comment: Great! If you found a solution, you might want to post your own answer so that people can use it should they find this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because the System I described was Alfresco - app called "share" has CSRFPolicy which blocked https. According to this [solution](http://www.giuseppeurso.eu/en/alfresco-tips-and-tricks-13-csrf-filter-error-on-share-login-with-apache-mod_proxy-and-sslengine-on/):

1. Copy the "CSRFPolicy" default config from:

`TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/share/WEB-INF/classes/alfresco/share-security-config.xml`

to:

`TOMCAT_HOME/shared/classes/alfresco/web-extension/share-config-custom.xml`

2. Add the attribute replace="true":

`<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="CSRFPolicy" replace="true">`

3. Update the properties *referer* and *origin* with FQDN (https) of the Apache VirtualHost

`<referer>https://HAProxyAddress/.*</referer>
 <origin>https://HAProxyAddress</origin>`

And that's all. It works for me.